# Ставится ли запятая перед словом «куда» в описанном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Но все ли имеют представление **куда** потратить выигранные деньги?

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре Ефремовой:
[**куда**](http://www.endic.ru/ozhegov/Kuda-13772.html), наречие
3. Употребляется как союзное слово, **присоединяя придаточные предложения**: места, изъяснительные и определительные.

*Но все ли имеют представление, **куда** потратить выигранные деньги?*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором придаточная часть отделяется запятой.

*Муртаев целенаправленно шагал куда-то вверх по склону, как будто бы мог **иметь представление, куда** он идет* (А. Ильин. Мир Дженнифер).
*Но из тех троих, о которых я говорил, Тоня находится здесь, а Мануэль и Зина **не имеют представления, куда** она исчезла* (А. Белозерская. Стрела, попавшая в тебя).
*Сидя жарким новоорлеанским днем под тентом кафе, он даже **представить себе не мог, куда потратить** такую уйму денег* (Д. Гришэм. Король сделки).

[Сложноподчинённые предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, это придаточное предложение.